# How to get the url of the current svn repo?

Tags: linux, svn, command-line-interface

I have 2 svn checkouts that someone setup for me. Now I need to check these same files on another computer, but since I didn't check them out initially I don't know the urls to use when running the svn checkout command:

```
svn co WHAT_GOES_HERE?
```

Since these 2 checkouts already exist on one of my servers, is there a way to get the url of the repo from which they were initially checked out from?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can get the URL of the directory you are in, as well as the Repository Root and other info by running the following command in any of the checked out directories:

```
svn info
```

If you want a command that returns only the URL of the repository, perhaps for use in a script, then you can pass the following parameter:

```
svn info --show-item repos-root-url
```

It is worth noting that `--show-item` [is available in Subversion 1.9+](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#enhancements). In older versions you can use the following snippet the achieve similar result:

```
svn info | grep 'Repository Root' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Same thing for windows:

   **svn info | findstr /C:"Repository Root: "**

Comment: To get the relative path for the repository (useful in addition to root URL): svn info --show-item relative-url

Answer (score 13):

For SVN 1.7 I had to use

```
svn info | grep '^URL' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

I hope this helps anyone else that comes here with a newer SVN

Comment: The accepted answer is still working for `svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled Apr 13 2013, 14:22:38`.

Comment: @dash17291 it "works" as in it prints something out but not the right info. It returns the repo root which is not what the asker wants. The root is not the repo url (at least not usually). With the above answer you will get http://repourl.com/root vs mine where you will get http://repourl.com/root/branch/branch_name or whatever you have checked out.

Comment: This also matches "Relative URL" using svn 1.8.10. The grep should be changed to `grep "^URL"`

Answer (score 4):

No need to grep, just use AWK for the search and delimiting the string
   `svn info | awk '/^URL/{print $2}'`